# Is there a way to implement sample weights?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, sample

I'm using statsmodels for logistic regression analysis in Python. For example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
x = arange(0,1,0.01)
y = np.random.rand(100)
y[y<=x] = 1
y[y!=1] = 0
x = sm.add_constant(x)
lr = sm.Logit(y,x)
result = lr.fit().summary()
```

But I want to define different weightings for my observations. I'm combining 4 datasets of different sizes, and want to weight the analysis such that the observations from the largest dataset do not dominate the model.

Comment: statsmodels currently supports weights only for the linear regression model.

Comment: GLM with family binomial allows: `Binomial family models accept a 2d array with two columns. If supplied, each observation is expected to be [success, failure].` It might be possible to use this to define sample weights, but I never tried.

Comment: **update** GLM in statsmodels has now weights option for var_weights and freq_weights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took me a while to work this out, but it is actually quite easy to create a logit model in statsmodels with weighted rows / multiple observations per row. Here's how's it's done:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
logmodel=sm.GLM(trainingdata[['Successes', 'Failures']], trainingdata[['const', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']], family=sm.families.Binomial(sm.families.links.logit)).fit()
```

Comment: Thanks! Just an FYI (because I got an error that took me a few minutes to catch), whereas patsy within the ``glm(...)`` function will dummy-fy categorical variables for you, in the ``GLM(...)`` above you have to do it yourself, for ex. with ``pandas.get_dummies(...)``

Comment: This is quite unclear. Can you clarify how you are introducing weighting?

Comment: `Successes` and `Failures` within `trainingdata` refer to the number of observations of each. This number of observations therefore provides a weighting.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure About statsmodel,

But with scikit learn is very easy. You could use an [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier) with sample_weight

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
X = [[0., 0.], [1., 1.]]
y = [0, 1]
weight=[0.5,0.5]
#log implies logistic regression
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss="log" )
clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight =weight)
print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
```